# Auto-delete certain file extensions on my phone?

Tags: file-system, automation

How do I make my phone automatically delete certain file extensions? I'm on ICS, rooted.

For example, after connecting my phone to my mac, it will leave a .trashes file and other "." folders on my SD card. I want to make it so that the phone checks regularly and removes those extensions that I define. Another use case scenario is when I'm using an emulator such as GameBoid. I accidentally click on the Quick Save option and now there's a rogue *.ss0 file on my SD card. I want them deleted too.

I just flashed a new rom to my phone so I haven't re-downloaded Tasker yet so I also wanted to know if there's already a working solution around.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use automation apps or a script to delete files at certain interval.

Using [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid):

1. In the Trigger tab, in Date/Time section, select "Regular interval". Then set the interval the macro should run.
2. In the action tab,  in the File section, select "File Operation V2", choose delete. Select the directory that should be checked, then select "Specify File Pattern". For example enter *.ssO .
3. Give the macro a name and save it.

Every X time, the macro will check the folder you selected and deletes the files corresponding with the pattern.

In the example of the macro below, *.ssO files in .dthumb folder are deleted every 30 seconds.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app that removes it, called "Trashes".

[It can be found on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=33332716&postcount=1).